# Returning Value from 0/1 Grid

Tags: python, function, random

**Hey there!** 
I am new to Python and programming in general. I have found a way of printing a grid of random 0 and 1. I need to save these grids and to count the amount of 0's in them. This is what I have so far: (Im using Python 2.7)

```
import random
foo = ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
x = random.choice(foo)
A = [[random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo)],
[random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo)],
        [random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo)],
        [random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo)],
        [random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo), random.choice(foo)]]


print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
          for row in A]))
```

Comment: What is your question? If you want people to give constructive criticism of this, Code Reviews is your place.

Comment: Why not have `foo` be a list of `[0, 1]`?

Comment: Tip: check out `for` loops

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ because they want `'0'` to have 60% probability.

Comment: @COLDSPEED 
Because i might need a certain proportion of 0 and 1s

Comment: @Ads5 Err, I don't know if `choice` picks items uniformly, so this might not give you what you're looking for. Also, why not select integers? Then you can do something clever with `sum`.

Comment: @progo I will check it outh thx

Answer (score 1):

To count the amount of `'0'`s in your matrix, you could do:

```
sum(sum(x == '0' for x in r) for r in A)
```

To generate the matrix, you can save yourself some code and do

```
A = [[random.choice(foo) for _ in range(4)] for __ in range(5)]
```

If you want to store the string representation anyways, there's an even easier to read way:

```
s = '\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
          for row in A])
print(s)
print(s.count("0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the amount of 0s you can use this

```
count0s = [item for sublist in A for item in sublist].count('0')
```

To store the grids you can use a list and append to it. Like this:

```
gridList = []
grid = '\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
  for row in A])
gridList.append(grid)
```

Comment: Thanksl! I am not as quick as you all. I will review all your options and try to use the best and post an update soon!

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend, to add a for-loop. To get the same results do

```
for i in range(n):   
   A[i] = radom.choice(foo)
```

n is the length of your Array
and to count add a variable berfore the loop, like

```
countZeros =  0   
countOnes  = 0
```

and in the loop add

```
if  a == 0:   
    countZeros++  
else:   
    countOnes++
```

Comment: Careful, incrementation doesn't work like that in Python.

Comment: This is just invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest using actual `0` and `1` instead of `'0'` and `'1'`. Also, you can use list-multiplication for `foo` and list-comprehensions (but *not* list-multiplications!) for `A` to make the code a bit clearer. Then, you can just get the `sum` of `sum`s and subtract that from the total number of elements in `A`.

```
>>> foo = [0] * 3 + [1] * 2
>>> A = [[random.choice(foo) for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(5)]
>>> A
[[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]]
>>> sum(map(len, A)) - sum(map(sum, A))
12
```

(Of course, if you know the dimensions of `A` you do not have to `sum` the `len`s.)

Or use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (also works with strings):

```
>>> collections.Counter(x for a in A for x in a)
Counter({0: 12, 1: 8})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear all sorry for the long wait! 
I had a friend help me and this what he came up with:

```
##Printing the Grid##
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as nprand

def create_matrix():
  # determine the random number of ones and zeros to be put into the lists
  c0_min = 20 # minimal number of zeros
  c0_var = 5 # range of possible additional zeros
  c0 = int(nprand.rand()*c0_var + c0_min) # count of zeros

  c1_min = 20 # ones
  c1_var = 20 
  c1 = int(nprand.rand()*c1_var + c1_min) # count of zeros

  # construct a long list with ones and zeros of random order
  # items
  items = [0,]*c0 + [1,]*c1
  random.shuffle(items)

  # determine the length of the rows 1-4
  # there is a minimal length + a variable length
  # len of rows
  lmin = 10
  rowcount = 4
  spacemax = 5

  # determine the number of characters that are freely assignable (total number minus minimal length)
  l_temp = c0+c1-lmin*rowcount # variable assignable characters

  # divide residual characters with respect to random weights among the rows
  l_weights = nprand.rand(4)
  l_weights = l_temp*l_weights/sum(l_weights)
  s_count = nprand.randint(0,spacemax,4)

  # calculate the final lengths of the rows
  r1 = lmin + int(l_weights[0])
  r2 = lmin + int(l_weights[1])
  r3 = lmin + int(l_weights[2])
  r4 = lmin + int(l_weights[3])

  # construct the strings by iterating the previously shuffled character list
  s1 = ''.join([str(i) for i in [' ', ]*s_count[0] + items[:r1]])
  s2 = ''.join([str(i) for i in [' ', ]*s_count[1] +  items[r1:(r1+r2)]])
  s3 = ''.join([str(i) for i in [' ', ]*s_count[2] +  items[(r1+r2):(r1+r2+r3)]])
  s4 = ''.join([str(i) for i in [' ', ]*s_count[3] +  items[(r1+r2+r3):]])

  # return row 1-4, number of zeros, number of ones.
  return (s1, s2, s3, s4, c0, c1)

m = create_matrix()
print m[0]
print m[1]
print m[2]
print m[3]
print m[4], m[5]
```